# OpenGL ES for android, modeling furniture

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertices

I am currently playing around with OpenGL ES for Android. I have decided to set myself the task of making a chair. Do I have to code each individual vertex or is there a way to multiply one set and transform them 10 units to the left.

For example, instead of having to code out each leg, can I multiply one into four and have them at different postions?

And if so is this possible outside of the rendering class?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily using `glTranslate()` function between each time you draw a chair leg. If you imagine drawing on a piece of paper where your hand is locked in position and can only draw the same chair leg in the same place each time, glTranslate() moves the piece of paper under your hand between drawing each chair leg.

However, for most complex models like a chair, you may want to consider making them using a 3D modelling software package, such as [blender](http://www.blender.org/) (which is free). When you save it as a file, the file actally contains all the vertices. Depending on which file format you save as, you can then write some code to load the file, parse it to extract the vertices, and then use those vertices to draw the chair.